# TSQL Get partial string of DateTime value?

Tags: t-sql

I have the following TSQL query to get date time value different:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, EndDtField - StartDtField, 120) AS Duration
  FROM myTable;
```

The result will be:

```
  Duration
  1900-01-01 23:02:04.000
  ....
```

I tried to get partial string from the result like this `01 23:02:04.000` by using `RIGHT()` function (actually preferably in the format of `01 23:02:04` without `000`):

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(DATETIME, EndDtField - StartDtField, 120), 15) AS Duration
  FROM myTable;
```

The result is:

```
 Duration
 1 1900 11:02PM
 ...
```

It looks like that the value of `RIGHT(..)` is a `datetime` value. Even I specify the `datetime` value in a format of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` but still I cannot get my expected result.  How can I get a partial string with only day and time(`dd hh:mi:ss`) out from the Duration? I really don't like to parse out `day`, `hour`, `minute` and `second` values and then to build a string.

Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need the following T-SQL:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, EndDtField - StartDtField, 121), 15) AS Duration FROM myTable;
```

Comment: when using CONVERT with date format 121, you can use char(23), which is the exact length needed.  "varchar" without a length will be varchar(30)

Comment: Great. I don't know that varchar is varchar(30) by default. Thanks for your information. Not sure if that default can be customized or not on sql server.

Answer (score 3):

There are SQL functions that do things similar to what you're trying:

[DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) will get a specific part of a date.  So you could use this with your Duration field to format it however you like.

[DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) will get the difference between two dates.  you may be able to replace the entire subtraction with this.

Comment: Those functions are good but as I understand that, I still have to call 4 DatePart to build a partial string (day, hour, minute and second).

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like that the value of RIGHT(..) is a datetime value.

No. The value of *[CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)* is a datetime value, because that's what you told it to convert to.    So then your call to RIGHT() does an implicit conversion to a string, where sql server gets to pick whatever convert format it wants (hint — the default looks like this: `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)` ).  You want to convert it to varchar yourself instead.

So, to recap.  You are currently doing this:

- Subtracting two dates (this is okay, but using DATEDIFF() would be better)
- Calling CONVERT() to create a datetime from that subtraction
- Calling RIGHT() on that datetime value, which forces sql server to do the default conversion to varchar

You want to do this:

- Convert to a specific string type before calling RIGHT()

or

- Call [DateDiff()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) up front using seconds for the datepart parameter
- Convert the returned seconds into a nice looking timespan in your client code.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head the easiest way to do this is to do your calculation twice and then concatenate the two strings. This can be performed in a single select statement.

```
-- example
select cast(day(getdate()) as varchar) + ' ' + convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)

-- your code
SELECT cast(day(EndDtField - StartDtField) as varchar) + ' ' +
       convert(varchar, EndDtField - StartDtField, 108) AS Duration
  FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting to varchar() before applying RIGHT()

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(DAY,(EndDtField  - StartDtField)) AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,(EndDtField  - StartDtField)) AS VARCHAR)+':'+CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE,(EndDtField  - StartDtField)) AS VARCHAR)+':'+CAST(DATEPART(SECOND,(EndDtField  - StartDtField)) AS VARCHAR)
  FROM myTable;
```

Bye

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert(DateTime,Convert(char,GetDate(),101),101)
```